# How to create a method that accepts and return generic type with his wrapper class

Tags: java, json, generics, gson, unmarshalling

I'm not sure how to classify what I'm trying to achieve
I think that I can define it like that:
I'm trying to create a method that will return a generic type with his wrapper class

I'll just show what I'm trying to do

I have a string that represents a JSON that I got from calling an endpoint

```
String httpBody = "{...}";
```

I have a class name EndPointResponse

```
public class EndPointResponse<T> {
    
    private T responseObj = null;
    ...
    
    public EndPointResponse(T responseObj, ...) {
        this.responseObj = responseObj;
        ...
    }
}
```

in another part of the code, I'm trying to create this object by calling another function

```
EndPointResponse<SomeObject> o1 = getEndPointResponse(httpBody, SomeObject.class);
```

I want to be able to get this object in more ways:

```
EndPointResponse<List<SomeObject>> o2 = getEndPointResponse(httpBody, SomeObject.class, List.class);
```

or

```
EndPointResponse<SomeWrapperObject<SomeObject>> o3 = getEndPointResponse(httpBody, SomeObject.class, SomeWrapperObject.class);
```

what I've done so far:

```
public static <T> EndPointResponse<T> getEndPointResponse(String httpBody, Class<T> classOfT){
    T result = getResultObject(httpBody, classOfT);
    if(result == null){
        return createEndPointResponse(httpBody, ...with some data);
    }
    return createEndPointResponse(result, ...with some other data);
}

public static <T> EndPointResponse<List<T>> getEndPointResponse(String httpBody, Class<T> classOfT, Class<?> wrapperClass){
    List<T> result = getResultObject(httpBody, classOfT, wrapperClass);
    if(result == null){
        return createEndPointResponse(httpBody, ...with some data);
    }
    return createEndPointResponse(result, ...with some other data);
}
```

```
private static <T> T getResultObject(String resultString, Class<T> classOfT){
    T resultObj = null;
    try{
        resultObj = gson.fromJson(resultString, classOfT);
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException e){
        ...some log
    }
    return resultObj;
}

private static <T> List<T> getResultObject(String resultString, Class<T> classOfT, Class<?> wrapperClass){
    List<T> resultObj = null;
    try{
        resultObj = gson.fromJson(resultString, getType(classOfT, wrapperClass));
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException e){
        ... some log
    }
    return resultObj;
}
```

```
private static <T> EndPointResponse<T> createEndPointResponse(T resultObj, ...){
    return new EndPointResponse<T>(resultObj, ...);
}

private static <T> EndPointResponse<List<T>> createEndPointResponse(List<T> resultObj, ...){
    return new EndPointResponse<List<T>>(resultObj, ...);
}
```

```
private static <T> Type getType(Class<T> classOfT, Class<?> wrapperClass){
    return new ParameterizedType() {
        private Type type;

        @Override
        public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[] {classOfT};
        }

        @Override
        public Type getRawType() {
            return wrapperClass;
        }

        @Override
        public Type getOwnerType() {
            return null;
        }

    };
}
```

so basically I'm trying to create another overloaded method that instead of a List class it will be any wrapper class that I want or even better is to generalize the List class overload method so it will support any wrapper class

something like this: (just an example it's not going to have the right syntax)

```
public static <T> EndPointResponse<W<T>> getEndPointResponse(String httpBody, Class<T> classOfT, Class<W> wrapperClass){
    W<T> result = getResultObject(httpBody, classOfT, wrapperClass);
    if(result == null){
        return createEndPointResponse(httpBody, ...with some data);
    }
    return createEndPointResponse(result, ...with some other data);
}

------------------------------------

private static <T> W<T> getResultObject(String resultString, Class<T> classOfT, Class<W> wrapperClass){
    W<T> resultObj = null;
    try{
        resultObj = gson.fromJson(resultString, getType(classOfT, wrapperClass));
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException e){
        ... some log
    }
    return resultObj;
}

------------------------------------

private static <T> EndPointResponse<W<T>> createEndPointResponse(W<T> resultObj, ...){
    return new EndPointResponse<W<T>>(resultObj, ...);
}
```

does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve that?
any help or constructive review will be appreciated :)
thanks

Comment: I haven't read your question in depth, but would something like `public static <T> T fromJson(final Gson gson, final JsonReader jsonReader, final TypeToken<? extends T> typeToken) { return gson.fromJson(jsonReader, typeToken.getType()); }` for you (the second parameter is supposed to create overloads according to `Gson` overloads)?